# Importing a Private Key to Keychain returns EINVAL error

Tags: macos, cocoa, keychain

I am trying to import RSA private keys into the keychain using my application. The first time I import a key using SecKeychainImport() the operation is successful, a subsequent import gives me an EINVAL (100022) error.

This does not happen if I quit and relaunch the app between two imports. I am including the source code below.

> ```
>     CFArrayRef array = (CFArrayRef)[NSMutableArray array];
>
>     SecExternalFormat format = kSecFormatUnknown;
>
>     //We are always storing a private key…
>     SecExternalItemType type = kSecItemTypePrivateKey;
>
>     SecKeyImportExportParameters params;
>
>     SecKeychainRef keychain;
>
>     SecKeychainCopyDefault(&keychain);
>
>     memset(&params, 0, sizeof(params));
>
>     params.version = SEC_KEY_IMPORT_EXPORT_PARAMS_VERSION;
>     params.flags = kSecKeyNoAccessControl;
>     params.keyUsage = CSSM_KEYUSE_ANY;
>     params.keyAttributes = CSSM_KEYATTR_EXTRACTABLE;
>
>     err = SecKeychainItemImport((CFDataRef)data,
>                                          (CFStringRef)@"pem",
>                                          &format,
>                                          &type,
>                                          0,
>                                          NULL,
>                                          keychain,
>                                          &array);
>     if(err == noErr)
>     {
>         //Change the kSecKeyPrintName attribute of the keychain item.
>     }
>
>     else
>     {
>         //Handle the error by displaying appropriate alert.
>     }
> ```

Am I missing anything obvious?

Comment: Shouldn't the sixth parameter be `&params` instead of NULL?

Comment: Also, on which OS version did you try this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the `CSSM_KEYATTR_PERMANENT` bit in params.keyAttribute. On Lion, I can import multiple PEM-armoured RSA private keys (generated with `openssl genrsa`) into a keychain if I explicitly set this attribute. If I don't, I get `errSecItemNotFound` (-25300) when importing the very first key.

(Don't forget to remove `kSecKeyNoAccessControl` before deploying this code in production. Also, if you generate the key yourself, consider using `SecKeyGenerate`/`SecKeyGenerateSymmetric` instead.)